# Passing Variable To Function Changes Address Location in C

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing, memory-address, memcpy

Having an odd issue here with passing an argument to a function.

The argument is a struct, defined as:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
 typedef struct {
     struct {
         uint8_t opcode;
         uint8_t type;
         union {
             uint8_t attr;
             struct {
                 unsigned int reserved : 6;
                 unsigned int sequence : 2;
             };
         };
         uint8_t bytes;
     } header;
     uint8_t payload[15];
 } message_t;
 #pragma pack(pop)
```

I have a function that declares this struct as:

```
void func1(void) {
    message_t response;
```

Within this function I pass it as an argument to another function:

```
    func2(response);
```

Within `func2` I have another struct declared and it is defined as:

```
 #pragma pack(push,1)
 typedef struct {
     struct {
         uint8_t op_code;
         avneraIDs_t IDs;
         uint8_t length;
     } header;
     uint8_t payload[30];
 } frame_t;
 #pragma pack(pop)
```

This struct is declared within `func2` as:

```
frame_t frame;
```

`frame` will have some data copied into it, and the data within its `payload` element is what I want copied into the `response` struct.

So now in `func2` i have a call to `memcpy`.

```
memcpy((uint8_t *)&response, frame.payload, (frame.header.length - 1));
```

I have verified that `frame.header.length` is equal to 20, and now minus 1 would copy over 19 bytes of data. `response` has a width of 19 bytes so it should be fine.

After performing the `memcpy`, I print out the contents of `response` and the contents look correct.

After returning to `func1` I print the contents of `response` again. And now the contents are gone, it's empty again.

So what I did to debug this was I printed the address location of `response` within the context of `func1` and I get the address `0x2000a470`.

If I print the address location of `response` within the context of `func2` I get the address `0x2000a484`.

If I print the memory starting at address `0x2000a484`, I see the data that should be in `response`.

Why did the address for `response` change as soon as I passed it to another function?

Also as some extra information, I am writing in C, using GCC, and an ST Arm Core MCU.

Comment: I think that is too much of a code puzzle, could you try for a more coherent [mcve]?

Comment: `response` is passed by value to `func2`..

Comment: Note: Do not expect `union {
             uint8_t attr;
             struct {
                 unsigned int reserved : 6;
                 unsigned int sequence : 2;
             };
         };` to overlay the `uint8_t` and the bit-fields in a portable manner.

Comment: "After returning to func1...." - That itself is telling and there is no way to know for sure without seeing code.  Given how you're using `response` the only way this code stand a hope's chance of working is if it is a global. And that isn't the case in your code. You're using `func2(response);`, which means you're providing it by-value to `func2`. The caller's argument will remain unchanged. Pass it by address to `func2` changign it to accept a pointer as its formal parameter. Finally, change the `&response` usage in `func2` to simply `response`, as it will already a proper pointer.

Comment: To simplify what @WhozCraig said, the variable `response` inside `func2()` is a *copy* of the variable from `func1()`. Changes you make to the copy don't affect the original. You need to pass a pointer to get the effect of passing by reference.

Comment: @WhozCraig Wow, I cannot believe I didn't realize that. Sometimes it just takes a separate set of eyes to make you see the obvious after staring at it for so long. Thanks for this! Changed it to accept a pointer and it works now. How do I mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: OT: your 'struct' typedef is missing key elements, like `tag` names and `field` names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're propagating pass-by-value between `func1` and `func2`. Your code has a function,

```
void func2(message_t response) // <<==== response gets value from caller
{
    memcpy(&response, ....) // <<==== modify local response; caller is unaffected.
}

void func1()
{
    message_t respnose;
    func2(response); // <<==== PASSED BY VALUE
}
```

C being pass-by-value, you need to craft the value to allow the modification you want:

```
void func2(message_t *response) // <<==== receiving address of caller's response
{
    memcpy(response, ...); // <<=== using address of caller's response.
}

void func1()
{
    message_t response;
    func2(&response); // <<==== passing address of our response
}
```

That should fix your issue.